# error: At least one of apiVersion, kind and name was changed

Tags: kubernetes

Why am I getting an error when I try to change the `apiVersion` of a deployment via `kubectl edit deployment example` ?

Do I have to delete and recreate the object?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're getting this because there are only certain attributes of a resource that you may change once it's created. ApiVersion, Kind, and Name are some of the prime identifiers of a resource so they can't be changed without deleting/recreating them.